# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'”

Tags: php, error-handling, single-quotes

```
echo '<a href="'. $site_url .'" onclick=" window.open('. $refferal_url .'); ">';
```

results

```
<a href="http://example.com/" onclick=" window.open(http://example.com/some-url/); ">
```

The problem is i can't get to put single quote before and after `http://example.com/some-url/`

because i always get the error.

How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of manually fiddling in / escaping quotes, appending the value per [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) / [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) would be most correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the single quotes because they are in a single-quoted string. Add `\'` where you want the single quotes.

Example:

```
echo '<a href="'. $site_url .'" onclick=" window.open(\''. $refferal_url .'\'); ">';
```

By the way, "referral" has two `r`s, not two `f`s.